# How to correctly extract strings in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, string

Through adding and removing certain parts of my app, I was able to determine that the following lines creating java fields for string codes was causing a crash in my app (starting with a white screen, then goes black and says the app is not responding);

```
private final String HIGH_SCORE = getString(R.string.highscore_code);
private final String CURRENT_SCORE = getString(R.string.currentscore_code);
```

This is my strings.xml file, which I expected to be the source of these strings using this code from the research I conducted online;

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My App</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_my_menu">MyMenu</string>

    <string name="highscore_code">HIGH_SCORE</string>
    <string name="currentscore_code">LAST_SCORE</string>
</resources>
```

I would highly appreciate if anyone here knows how to correctly load the strings.

Comment: post your stacktrace

Comment: where are you calling the getString() in your code.

Comment: Sorry, but what is a stacktrace? I'm a little new to Android Studio

Comment: Apology accepted. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors pro tip: try to google before you're asking, you'd be surprised how many questions will be answered by google ;)

Comment: the java code is being called in my MainGame class, which inherits from Activity. It is my major Activity which loads upon the app starting.

Comment: I don't think I have a stack-trace as I am testing by simply downloading the application onto my phone and then installing and running it

Comment: @superhacker if your device is connected to system and detected by Android Studio then you can refer the logcat (type :error highlighted in red) which will give you complete stacktrace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getString(...)` needs a properly initialized android component (Fragment, Activity, Service, ....). That is it must be in the right life cycle state.

For activities that is when or after `onCreate` and before `onDestroy` is called. For fragments that would be `onAttach` and `onDetach`, and so on. You should probably google for *Activity life cycle* or *Fragment life cycle*.

So you **cannot** use `getString()` to initialize class constants.

You can set variables by overriding `onCreate` in an Activity.

```
private String highScore;
private String currentScore;

@override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(<your_layout>);

    highScore = getString(R.string.highscore_code);
    currentScore = getString(R.string.currentscore_code);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Resources res=c.getResources();
String name=res.getString(R.string.name);
```

Where c is the Context object.

Comment: by c I assume you mean the current class?

Comment: No, it's the **Context**.

Comment: In which method are you executing these statements?  private final String HIGH_SCORE = getString(R.string.highscore_code);
private final String CURRENT_SCORE = getString(R.string.currentscore_code);

Comment: would getApplicationContext() be sufficient for that?

Comment: the statements are being executed in that part between the class name declaration and the constructor, where you declare fields (I feel like such a noob writing this)

Comment: You cannot write code statements at places where you declare fields, aren't you getting any compile time error. If you are not getting any compile time errors then you are writing it inside a method , I am asking which method is that. You know what a method is right?

Comment: If you are inside a `Fragment`, you must get the Fragment's **Activity's Context**: `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

Comment: I indeed know what a method is. It is definitely where you declare fields. Btw, my mistake if it makes a difference - there is no constructor, the fields are declared between the class name declaration and the onCreate method

Comment: thanks for the help guys. It turns out the correct solution was to obtain the strings in the onCreate method

Comment: This is because onCreate() is a Activity class method and the instance of Context is readily available here. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the fields `HIGH_SCORE` and  `CURRENT_SCORE` as class fields.
Here you cannot access the method `getString()` without a valid `Context` `Reference`  since the method is definded in the `Context` class.
So you need to call it after the `onCreate()` call back in an `Activity`.